# Adding dictionary on Kindle's Mac app

Tags: mac, kindle, dictionary

I want to change the default dictionary on Kindle app on mac. How do I do it.

I have downloaded my favorite dictionary in .mobi format

Comment: This does not give answer for Kindle app for Mac-OSx